# Directory indexes are not allowed here

Tags: django, web, static

I am new to Django, but have tried innumerable things. We're using Django 1.7.3. I need to be able to see the contents of to load into a JS program. I can access static files, but can not get the index of folders.

I have defined in settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Currently my URL code looks like:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
#...
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': '/static/', 'show_indexes' : True}),
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Daniel Roseman may be correct despite having seen other people do this. However, instead of switching servers, which is essentially impossible for me, I created a page with a list of the directory in it.... sort of a hack, but who cares, it works.

Answer (score 4):

Django's static serving library doesn't do directory indexes.

You should use a real static server; you'll need to do that for production anyway.